# Pydantic does not validate when assigning a number to a string

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

When assigning an incorrect attribute to a Pydantic model field, no validation error occurs.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class pyUser(BaseModel):
    username: str

    class Config:
        validate_all = True
        validate_assignment = True

person = pyUser(username=1234)
person.username
>>>1234
try_again = pyUser()

pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError:
[ErrorWrapper(exc=MissingError(), loc=('username',))]
<class '__main__.pyUser'>
```

How can I get pydantic to validate on assignment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is expected behaviour according to the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/):

> `str`
>
> strings are accepted as-is, `int`, `float` and `Decimal` are coerced using `str(v)`

You can use the `StrictStr`, `StrictInt`, `StrictFloat`, and `StrictBool` types to prevent coercion from compatible types.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictStr


class pyUser(BaseModel):
    username: StrictStr

    class Config:
        validate_all = True
        validate_assignment = True


person = pyUser(username=1234)  # ValidationError `str type expected`
print(person.username)
```