# Integer and string cannot be distinguished with pydantic

Tags: python, validation, marshmallow, pydantic

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class AuthenticationResponseSchema(BaseModel):
    type: str
```

```
schema = AuthenticationResponseSchema(type=1)
```

Now I'm changing marshmallow to pydantic for schema, model ...

But pydantic schema did not validated `type` when data response.

data type of `type` is string, but the integer passed too.

what is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65213960/13782669

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As statad in [the documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/)

> strings are accepted as-is, int float and Decimal are coerced using str(v), bytes and bytearray are converted using v.decode(), enums inheriting from str are converted using v.value, and all other types cause an error

If you want to force string, there's this thing called [`Strict Types`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#strict-types), so you can use `StrictStr`.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictStr


class AuthenticationResponseSchema(BaseModel):
    type: StrictStr


schema = AuthenticationResponseSchema(type=1)
```

Comment: this seems to violate the spirit of strong typing and the principle of least surprise - I do not like this design decision